# What system would I build for the human brain to be able to experience 400 years of earth time events in only 4 hours?

Tags: science-based, technology, brain

preferably need knowledge about

1. brain-computer interfaces
2. brain neural enhancement
3. brain in a vat
4. the novel *SHADOWS* by John Saul
5. perspective in which you see the computer as the thing which allows the brain to improve itself faster than evolution can.
6. evolutionary biology
7. entropy and the pyramid of power

Comment: These sorts of open ended questions are a poor match for Stack Exchange's question and answer format.  That being said, I recommend watching Agents of Shield and finding out where TAHITI is.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. It's pretty unclear what you are asking. To me it sounds like "a history book" is a good way to experience thousands of years in few hours reading. You can find more info on what to put in a good question by visiting our [help]

Comment: I'm trying to ask a question in which I do illegal experimentation on my own brain and subsequently, achieve the ability to live in a slow motion world such that 4 hours in real time is effectively 400 years in my slow motion space-time dimension. The ambiguity in the question is evident and i will try to remove it, however, my world building fantasy is inspired by John Saul's novel SHADOWS.